Angular: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setValue')
i want to fill in a form with some given data, as it may be clear in the codes; but when the form is in another route and i change the route i get this error. although i Get the data, and i can make sure to see it on Console.
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule, NgForm} from "@angular/forms";
import {MemberService} from "../shared/member.service";
import {MemberModel} from "../shared/member.model";
import {NgForOf} from "@angular/common";
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    NgForOf
  ],
  templateUrl: './edit.component.html',
  styleUrl: './edit.component.css'
})
export class EditComponent implements OnInit , OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('memberForm') memberForm!: NgForm;
  newMember!: MemberModel;

  editedMember!: MemberModel;

  constructor(private svc:MemberService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.editedMember = this.svc.getMember(id);
    console.log(this.editedMember);
    this.memberForm.setValue(
      {
        name: this.editedMember.name,
        surname: this.editedMember.surname,
        nickname: this.editedMember.nickname,
        bio: this.editedMember.bio,
      }
    )
  }}

when i don't change the route, and the form (Edit component) is on the same component as the data, everything works well.
But I want to have the form and the data in different routes (pages)

i don't understand the question properly, is it like you don't get the values when the id is invalid ( like not getting exact values for the this.editedMember = this.svc.getMember(id);  action ) @sahar-manouchehri

Try moving this.memberForm.setValue to ngAfterViewInit() from ngOnInit() because @ViewChild variables are not initialized in ngOnInit().

Your form doesn't need to be a viewchild.
You can just set <form [formGroup]="memberForm">
and declare the memberForm as memberForm: FormGroup;
which you initialize in your ngOnInit memberForm = new FormGroup({...config goes here...});
If the memberform gets declared somewhere else, than as N.F. said, its not available in your ngOnInit() yet but ngAfterViewInit()

Thank you every one, I set a Timeout for my setValue, and it worked! But i will try ngAfterViewInit() too, it may be a better approach

A setTimeout will basically run after the view has been initialize so thats probably why it works, but overall it will make your application slower

You can able to access template by declaring viewchild with static variable as true. This make template variable available in ngOnInit hook itself.
@ViewChild('memberForm', {static: true}) memberForm!: NgForm;

